# Examples of non-trivial closed subschemes of a complete non-projective non-singular variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, big-list

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.
A variety over $k$ is a separated integral scheme of finite type over $k$.
Let $V$ be a complete non-projective non-singular variety over $k$.
Let $Z$ be a closed subset of $V$.
Let $\mathcal I$ be the ideal sheaf which defines $Z$ as a reduced closed subscheme of $V$.
$\mathcal I^n$ defines a closed subscheme $Z_n$ of $V$ for every integer $n \ge 1$.
I would like to know examples of closed subschemes of $V$ other than $Z_n$.

**Remark**
The more examples, the better.
Please don't think that the question would be solved if one example would be given.

**Edit(March 23, 2014)**
I have just posted [a similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161123/examples-of-non-trivial-irreducible-closed-subschemes-of-a-complete-non-projecti) in MathOverflow.

Comment: I don't understand this question. All closed subschemes come from some ideal sheaf?

Comment: @AlexYoucis In other words, I'm asking an example of a non-trivial ideal sheaf whose support is a given closed subset.

Comment: But, what makes it non-trivial? If I am understanding your post, you are discounting all ideal sheaves coming from closed subschemes?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm asking an example of ideal sheaf other than $\mathcal I^n$.

Comment: But it sounds like you're talking about $\mathcal{I}^n$ for any $\mathcal{I}$ coming from a closed subscheme, which is all possible $\mathcal{I}$!

Comment: (of course in my previous statement I meant all quasicoherent $\mathcal{I}$ :) )

Comment: @AlexYoucis No. There is only a unique ideal sheaf $\mathcal I$ for a given closed subset $Z$ which makes it a *reduced* closed subscheme.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand then. If you were discussing the affine case, then you'd be asking for ideals which aren't powers of a radical ideal, is that correct?

Comment: @AlexYoucis That's about it, but I'm asking about a *complete* non-projective non-singular variety. An affine variety is never complete unless it's a point.

Comment: [*In other words, I'm asking an example of a non-trivial ideal sheaf whose support is a given closed subset.*]
Oops. I'm asking an example of a non-trivial ideal sheaf $\mathcal I$ such that the support of $\mathcal O_V/\mathcal I$ is a given closed subset.

Answer (score 4):

Take the  subscheme consisting of a double point and a simple point !

**Edit**
  As requested in the comments, here are  a few more details.
Choose two closed points $x,y\in V$.
Let $\mathcal I(x)\subsetneq   \mathcal O_V$ and $\mathcal I(y)\subsetneq   \mathcal O_V$ be the ideal sheaves of these two points considered as reduced closed points of $V$.
Then define the ideal sheaf $\mathcal K\subset \mathcal O_V$ to be the unique sheaf of ideals of $\mathcal O_V$ satisfying:
a) $\mathcal K|(V\setminus \{y\})=\mathcal I(x)|(V\setminus \{y\})$
b) $\mathcal K|(V\setminus \{x\})=\mathcal I(y)^2|(V\setminus \{x\})$
If $\mathcal I$ is the ideal sheaf of the reduced subscheme $Z=\{x,y\}$ we then have $$ \cdots\subsetneq \mathcal I^n\subsetneq \cdots \mathcal I^2 \subsetneq    \mathcal K  \subsetneq   \mathcal I  \subsetneq   \mathcal O_V  $$ so that $\mathcal K$ defines a non-reduced subscheme $Z'$ whose reduction is $Z$ and satisfying   $$Z=Z_1\subsetneq Z'\subsetneq Z_2\subsetneq \cdots\subsetneq Z_n\subsetneq\cdots V$$  so that $Z'$ is distinct from the all the thickenings $Z_n$ of $Z$ defined by the $\mathcal I^n$.

Comment: Georges, how precisely does one rigorously define this? Clearly in local coordinates you mean $V(x_0^2,x_1)$, but I don't know how to define this for a general scheme. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Alex, define the ideal $\mathcal I|U$  on some affine open subscheme $U$ in which you choose two closed points   and extend that  ideal  by $\mathcal O_X$  outside of the two closed points.

Comment: [*and extend that ideal by $\mathcal O_X$ outside the two closed points*]
I'm afraid I don't understand this.
Could you explain how precisely you define this ideal sheaf on $X$?

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. By the way, your example makes me wonder if there is an example of a non-trivial subscheme of $V$ whose underlying topological space is irreducible.

Comment: Dear Makoto, you are welcome. Yes, I think there are irreducible examples: you should take a reduced subscheme and fatten just one point on it. This would correspond in commutative algebra to an embedded prime ideal in the primary decomposition of an ideal. But I haven't done any  calculation, so I can't formally guarantee that it works.